# Is every analytic hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^n$ cut out by one holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Is every analytic hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^n$ cut out by one holomorphic function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; this follows from $H^1(\mathbf C^n, \mathcal O^\times)=0$. See Griffiths & Harris, Chapter 0, Section 3 (p. 47 in my edition).